# Zend Imap: 'fsockopen(): unable to connect to imap.mydomain.com:143 (No route to host)'

Tags: php, sockets, email, zend-framework, imap

I'm trying to use the [Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/) to check an imap email account. So I supply the host ('imap.mydomain.com'), the port (143), and the username and password. I know for a fact that these are correct, since I checked them using Thunderbird. I then inserted them in the Zend functionality, but I get an error saying:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'fsockopen(): unable to connect to imap.mydomain.com:143 (No route to host)' in /home/kramer65/my-project/external/zend/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Imap.php:90
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Zend\Stdlib\ErrorHandler::addError(2, 'fsockopen(): un...', '/home/kramer65/my...', 90, Array)
#1 /home/kramer65/my-project/external/zend/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Imap.php(90): fsockopen('imap.mydomain.com', 143, 113, 'No route to hos...', 30)
#2 /home/kramer65/my-project/external/zend/library/Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php(203): Zend\Mail\Protocol\Imap->connect('imap.mydomain.com', 143, false)
#3 /home/kramer65/my-project/communication/EmailBox.php(51): Zend\Mail\Storage\Imap->__construct(Array)
#4 /home/kramer65/my-project/daemon/SupportEmail.php(59): my-project\common_lib\communication\EmailBox->__construct(2, Array)
#5 /home/kramer65/ in /home/kramer65/my-project/external/zend/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Imap.php on line 93
```

Line 90 in Mail/Protocol/Imap.php reads:

```
$this->socket = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, self::TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
```

So here are my questions: what is exactly wrong? Is it that it can't find imap.mydomain.com? And if so, why not? How would I be able to find out why it can't reach that domain, even though my thunderbird installation can? Or is something else wrong? Have I made a mistake? In short; how can I debug this?

All tips are welcome!

Comment: This has to do with the server itself, DNS settings. Why don't you try to use direct IP and not hostname?

Comment: Can you ping `imap.mydomain.com` from the machine running the code? I doubt it.

Comment: I could ping the mailserver from my development machine, but imap didn't work. Turns out the Mailserver had some weird iptables configurations and I had to use TLS. Thanks for getting me on the right path!

Comment: You might liketo add an answer to your own question and accept it, so this question is visible as being "closed".